# the data cannot insert using textView using MYSQL server

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, json

help me.. this something wrong with the JSON thing on code below. cannot parse to php file.. android apps link with phpmyadmin@MySQL server.... using php file. this send data using TextView. the data is passing from other page. and hold it in textview below. but while the data want to send. the JSON doesnt not function and the apps i create are stop and detected failure application. my php file have no problem but in this code i dont know what problem.. it doesnt reach the try funcion i think.. just need help for me insert data from this apps to mysql server using php file.

```
         @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity3.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Sending Aduan....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
         }

         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


             String nama = txtView1.getText().toString();
             String alamat = txtView2.getText().toString();
             String no_ic = txtView3.getText().toString();
             String mobile = txtView4.getText().toString();
             String telefon = txtView5.getText().toString();
             String email = txtView6.getText().toString();
             String kenyataan = txtView7.getText().toString();
             String pelaksana = txtView8.getText().toString();
             String lokasi = txtView9.getText().toString();
             String daerah = txtView10.getText().toString();    

             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama", nama));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alamat", alamat));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_ic", no_ic));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telefon", telefon));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kenyataan", kenyataan));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pelaksana", pelaksana));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("daerah", daerah));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lokasi", lokasi));



             JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_aduan,"POST", params);

             Log.e("Create Response", json.toString());

             try {
                 int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                 if (success == 1) {

                   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Rujukan.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 finish();
                } else {
                }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
             return null;
         }


         protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

             pDialog.dismiss();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM :**

you are trying to do UI related task from `doInBackground` method of `AsyncTask`.

**SOLUTION :**

Because it's not possible to access UI elements from UI thread so move all items form `doInBackground`  to `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` as :

```
String nama,alamat,no_ic,mobile,telefon;
String email,kenyataan,pelaksana,lokasi,daerah;

 @Override
         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute();

              nama = txtView1.getText().toString();
              alamat = txtView2.getText().toString();
              no_ic = txtView3.getText().toString();
              mobile = txtView4.getText().toString();
              telefon = txtView5.getText().toString();
              email = txtView6.getText().toString();
              kenyataan = txtView7.getText().toString();
              pelaksana = txtView8.getText().toString();
              lokasi = txtView9.getText().toString();
              daerah = txtView10.getText().toString();  

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity3.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Sending Aduan....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
         }

         protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


             List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nama", nama));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alamat", alamat));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("no_ic", no_ic));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", mobile));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telefon", telefon));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("kenyataan", kenyataan));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pelaksana", pelaksana));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("daerah", daerah));
             params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lokasi", lokasi));


             int success=0;
             JSONObject json = jsonParser.
               makeHttpRequest(url_create_aduan,"POST", params);

             Log.e("Create Response", json.toString());

             try {
                  success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  success=0;
                  }
             return ""+success;
         }


         protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                pDialog.dismiss();
                if (Integer.parseInt(result) == 1) {

                   Intent i = new Intent(
                   Current_Activity.this,Rujukan.class);
                 startActivity(i);
                 finish();
                } else {
                   //your task here
                }
         }
     }
```

Comment: @user1906140 then  past your latest log when app is crashing